# "Either Fmap" which Continues until a Right Result has been Reached

Tags: haskell, either

If `Either fmap` is

`(a -> b) -> p a a -> p a b`

which stops mapping once a `Left` is returned.

What's name or type signature for a function which doesn't stop until it gets a `Right` result.

I suspect a bifunctor, but I really need it spelled out - don't quite get the subtlety of the logic of these things yet.

Perhaps some sort of `fold` fits also...

Comment: Is `Either fmap` valid Haskell code?

Comment: Have you tried asking [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle)?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this question is asking. `Either fmap` means what? What is `p`? What's it mean for a function to "stop"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Data.Bifunctor.first :: (a -> b) -> Either a c -> Either b c
```

In ghci:

```
Data.Bifunctor> first (+1) (Left 0)
Left 1
Data.Bifunctor> first (+1) (Right 0)
Right 0
```